# How to get a notification when I exceed a set amount of RAM?

Tags: macos, memory, notifications

I've got 10GB of RAM in my 13" early 2011 MBP running the latest OS X 10.11.1 public beta, and [I've been trying to decide if I can tolerate the 8GB model when I get a new computer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/204801/less-ram-and-an-ssd-vs-more-ram-and-an-hdd). The answer to that question seems to think I can, but it'd be nice to have some empirical evidence to support that person's opinion. To that end, I want to be able to monitor when, in my daily use, my computer would explode if it only had 8GB.

Is there a way to configure my computer to alert me when its RAM usage exceeds 8GB?

Comment: Not sure it really works that way - it's not a question of how much RAM is used, as the system will try to use all it has, in case anything is needed again. It's really whether it's using the swap file that's more of an indicator, or if you see memory pressure rising.

Comment: @Tetsujin So what could I do to figure out if I can get the kind of performance I get now with 2GB less RAM?

Comment: Take 2GB out ? ;)

Comment: Honestly, that's not a bad idea. My 10GB is in the form of 2 and 8...

Comment: @user24601 Note that two 4 GB sticks should perform better than one 8 GB stick.